# Are there any alternatives to Genuine Fractals for seemingly lossless picture enlargement?

Tags: resize

Perhaps many of you have heard of the Photoshop extension called "Genuine Fractals" that can enlarge a bitmap (JPEG) picture without making it look worse.

Are there any alternatives? Ideally free or cheap 32-bit Windows and Linux applications are preferred but I'd like to know about any alternatives, including web-based services.

Comment: I've used fractal software before to enlarge images and I'm not convinced it's as magic as they claim.

Comment: I have used it once (to enlarge a photographic computer desktop "wallpaper" from 800x600 to 1280x1024) and it was indeed good, @DA01. Perhaps you were trying to enlarge the picture too much. Of course it can't make miracles but it is still much much better than ordinary widely used resize algorithms.

Comment: Photoshop has pretty much caught up to all those third party tools with its internal interpolation. Chances are Photoshop CC+ will do just as good a job.

Comment: Yea, I'd say a size increase of 50% isn't all that much. Photoshop should be able to handle that for you OK.